# Streaming live video and audio from iphone iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, streaming, video-streaming

First, I wish to emphasize the keyword **from**. There are a lot of questions and answers on this topic but I found that no answer provide a step by step road-map to achieve this.
**What I wish to achieve :**
I wish to stream the video and audio (live) being recorded from the camera of iPhone/iPad to my server. And that's it.
**What have I figured till now** :
I guess that we can't use HTTP live streaming because it's meant for server to client **and not** client to server. AV framework allows the output only in the form of a mov file.
**What am I not able to figure :**
I don't know how to get individual frames (live) and send them to my server one by one
PS: I really don't know anything about this... You are welcomed to oversimplify things. I am writing server in node.js

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Wowza GoCoder](http://www.wowza.com/addons/gocoder) iOS app.

It requires Wowza as the media server though, so you'll be able to provide full-features streaming to anyone you want.

Server side set up is done easily via [Wowza configs](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?500%5C) or by third-party [cloud control](http://blog.wmspanel.com/2013/08/support-for-wowza-gocoder.html) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the app is not free... Do you have an idea how such apps are created...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Please add anything here if you find a free app for the same. As for Wowza, it's not for free either but you need to have a media server anyway to host your live stream.